# Android crash report with lots of <OR> in stacktrace

Tags: java, android, google-play

Our app is minified and the deobfuscated mappings is uploaded to Play developer console so I am expecting the real line numbers translated when there is a crash. However, the latest stacktrace shows lots of  which is making it really hard to troubleshoot. Additionally there is no line number at all. Any idea how this can be improved?

An example stacktrace is like this. I have replaced real class and method names as `myclass1` and `mymethod0` to `mymethod8`. Not sure where are these `access$xxx` methods coming from.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myclass1.mymethod0(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod1(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod2(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod3(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod4(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod5(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod6(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$100(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$500(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$600(myclass1.java)
    at myclass1.mymethod7(myclass1.java)
    at myclass1.mymethod0(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod1(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod2(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod3(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod4(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod5(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod6(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$100(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$500(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$600(myclass1.java)
    at myclass1.mymethod0(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod1(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod2(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod3(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod4(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod5(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.mymethod6(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$100(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$500(myclass1.java)
    at <OR>.access$600(myclass1.java)
    at myclass1$6.mymethod9(myclass1.java)
```